# Insert Related List doesn't work for Calendars

Tags: 2010, web-part

I am creating a series of connected web parts to display meeting minutes & action items along with meetings.  I have created a lookup in my Document Library to the meeting event in the calendar.  When I add the calendar web part to the page, I would like to use **Web Part Tools** --> **Insert Related List** to add my document library, but this option is disabled.

I cannot make the connection by hand, for when I add my document library web part all the *Connections* options are disabled.

Any ways to make this work?